# возможно ли сделать мобильное приложение из одного webview?

Tags: ios, webview

Добрый день
У меня стоит задача, сделать мобильную версию своего saas сервиса под андроид и ios
но сам я владею только веб разработкой

мне пришла идея сделать приложение-оболочку, в которой будет только вызов webview с зашитым адресом(url) и все,
а весь контент будет загружаться с сервера
тогда я смогу сам развивать приложение и не нужно будет делать адаптацию под разные платформы (андроид и ios и другие)
я уже попробовал сделать такое приложение на адроиде, результат мне понравился

Теперь вопрос:

насколько я знаю, подобное приложение не разместят в appstore, есть ли какой то способ распространять такое приложение для ios?

спасибо

Comment: PhoneGap вам в помощь

Comment: @АндрейШпилевой, Меня тоже интересует данный вопрос! Можете ли Вы немного подробнее рассказать о PhoneGap? минусы и плюсы

Comment: @Maqsood - минус в том что очень сложно обойти встроенные ограничения. Также к минусам отнесу большой вес даже если очень мало чего реализовать. Плюс в быстром старте. Зная Веб необходимо 20 минут что бы написать свое первое приложение после прочтения документации и пары роликов в сети. Но если нужно просто отобразить сайт на устройстве, то лучше сделать активити с веб видом. Ну и по факту свой приметивный PhoneGap можно написать за пару часов, понятное дело что функционалом он не сравнится, но все же порой это лучше! Ну а если нужна кросплатформенность то только PhoneGap и его альтернативы!

Comment: @АндрейШпилевой, возможности Push-уведомлений имеются?

Comment: в нативной части приложения можно делать все что угодно, из того что реализовано на платформе

Answer (score 1):

Если вы знаете веб, посмотрите [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) (javascript который компилируется в нативное приложение) или [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) (javascript который запускается в веб вью).

Для любопытных, почему если просто загрузить сайт в веб вью эпл не пропустит в аппстор:

> 4.2 Minimum Functionality
>   Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store. If your App doesn't provide some sort of lasting entertainment value, or is just plain creepy, it may not be accepted. Apps that are simply a song or movie should be submitted to the iTunes store. Apps that are simply a book or game guide should be submitted to the iBooks Store.

Comment: React Native малость не про это. Он про управление настоящими, нативными виджетами с помощью JS. Никаких WebView.

Comment: @D-side человек говорит, что шарит в веб разработке, вот ему приблуда на JS. сам пусть разбирается подходит оно ему или нет

Answer (score 0):

Из личного опыта - создавал приложение, состоящее из одного `webView` в который выводился частично добавленный в пакет код сайта. Основные страницы брались потом из web. Приложение успешно размещено в App Store.

Другой опыт: приложение с небольшим нативным функционалом, все остальное загружается из web. Приложение также в App Store.

Apple опасается, что на ревью вы подадите один сайт, а после выхода подставите другой. Поэтому какой-то минимум надо зашить в приложение, можно в виде небольшого сайта.